# Updating an AND filter to OR filter Javascript

Tags: javascript, filter

I'm working on a JavaScript filter that needs to show all items that are tagged with the related values. At the moment I have it working so that it shows items that have have each of these values assigned rather than showing the items as long as they have one of the values assigned.

So for example, if I check Cats and Dogs, I want to show every post that has either of these values assigned, rather than just showing items that have both assigned.

My code example is below:

```
var $filterCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"]');
            $filterCheckboxes.on('change', function() {
                var selectedFilters = {};
                $filterCheckboxes.filter(':checked').each(function() {
                    if (!selectedFilters.hasOwnProperty(this.name)) {
                        selectedFilters[this.name] = [];
                    }
                    selectedFilters[this.name].push(this.value);
                });

                var $filteredResults = data;

                // console.log('filtered data: ' + $filteredResults);

                $.each(selectedFilters, function(name, filterValues) {
                    $filteredResults = $filteredResults.filter(function(item) {
                        var matched = false,
                            currentFilterValues = item.Tags;

                        console.log(currentFilterValues);

                        $.each(currentFilterValues, function(_, currentFilterValue) {
                            if ($.inArray(currentFilterValue, filterValues) != -1) {
                                matched = true;
                                return false;

                                console.log(currentFilterValue);
                            }
                        });
                        return matched;

                    });
                });
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: can you share the output of your `console.log`s and specify which output should have been different?

Comment: So when I click my first checkbox, I get this as the output:

(6) ["Blog", "Case Study", "Construction Finance", "Global Business Monitor", "Construction Finance", "Insight"]
(2) ["Blog", "Insight"]
(3) ["Blog", "Case Study", "Construction Finance"]
 ["Insight"]
(2) ["Insight", "Construction Finance"]

Comment: So thats showing every item that has a tag of blog and showing it, as soon as i check the next item, for example case study, then it would only show the items that have both. Where as I need to try and make it to just show all of the items that have either of those tags as opposed to both.

Comment: What is [6], [3], etc.. It will help if you can post the output with the code as comments.

Comment: Cool. In that case, please delete this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went down a different route and minimised the code to get it running the way I desired:

```
var $filterCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"], input[type="radio"]');
            $filterCheckboxes.on('change', function() {
                var $filteredResults = data;
                var selectedFilters = [];

                $filterCheckboxes.filter(':checked').each(function() {
                    selectedFilters.push(this.value);
                });

                $filteredResults = data.filter(function(item) {
                    return (_.intersection(item.Tags, selectedFilters).length > 0);
                });
            });
```

So now every time a checkbox was checked, it would see if the selected tag(s) matched the tags within the item(s), if so it would grab any matching items and show them in the list.